# Pointcloud value at a given index

Tags: ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using RealSense-415 camera to get RGB color image of size(480X640) and pointcloud data of length (307200 i.e., 480X640). I achieve this using the Python code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2 

def callback_ptclud(ptcloud_data):
    assert isinstance(ptcloud_data, PointCloud2)
    pt_gen = point_cloud2.read_points(ptcloud_data)
    for pt in pt_gen:
        print(pt)

def listener():
    rospy.Subscriber("/camera/depth_registered/points", PointCloud2, callback_ptclud)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("realsense_subscriber", anonymous=True)
   listener()
```

Now my questions are as follows,

1. As you can see that inside the `callback_ptclud()` function, I need to loop through all the data points of `pt_gen`  to access point-cloud data. Suppose, I need to access only the data in `pt_gen` at index `i=1000`. Is there a way to get to index value at `i` directly instead of looping through all `999` points?
2. Suppose that pointcloud data is aligned with color image and I want to retrieve the pointcloud value corresponding to the color image pixel index `px=240, py=320`. Then what will be the corresponding index value of `pt_gen`?

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325917/pointcloud-value-at-a-given-index/) by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2019-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. If you're not too bothered about performance you can use the [read_points_list method](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs_1_1point__cloud2.html#a406d497e318a6c9b4f40b94ed6175d30) instead this returns all the points in the point cloud as a list which you can index the one you want. This won't be very efficient though so you may need to write your own code to access  individual values directly from the raw data of the point cloud.

   points = point_cloud2.read_points_list(ptcloud_data)
   print points[50]

However this function internally will loop through all points to make the list. You can access the point directly but you'll have to use the `point_step`, `row_step` and `data` members directly then decode the type of point used in your point cloud. I'm not sure if any easier method than this exists unfortunately.

2. The points in structured point cloud like will be ordered using [Row-Major ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), so you can calculate the index of a particular pixel using the formula below:

   PointIndex = PixelX + ( PixelY * CloudWidth)

You can also find the width and height of this structured cloud from the [PointCloud2 message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) itself by accessing the `width` and `height` members. I recommend you use this approach so your code will be compatible with all structured point cloud messages.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

In order to extract the point data from the `data` buffer you'll want to use the python [struct.unpack_from](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) function, this with convert the byte buffer into the actual point data. If you just want your code to work with float 32 XYZ type point clouds then its fairly simple to hard code the structure in. The full PointCloud2 decoder can detect and work with all the different point types, but that is probably more complex than necessary in your case.

The code will look something like this:

```
index = (row*ptcloud_data.row_step) + (col*ptcloud_data.point_step)
(X, Y, Z) = struct.unpack_from('fff', ptcloud_data.data, offset=index)
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2019-06-16**:
I actually tried to use `point_step`, `row_step` and 'data' to retrieve individual values but unable to get the data as they are in bytes and I did not know how to get numerical values from a byte array. Can you please point me to some documentation on this. Thank you for your answer though.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-16**:
No worries, I've added an update showing you how to get the floating point values from the byte array.

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2019-06-16**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd Thank you for the updated answer. It really helped.